# Is there a way to use temporary list variable inside nested dict comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

this is what my dict looks like:

```
   ranked_imgs = {'d57b26aa-c8f8-4e08-9e8f-8aecd6e952a5': {'small': [],
      'medium': [['https://www.pablo-ruiz-picasso.net/images/works/261.jpg', 1]],
      'large': []},
     'b10ecfdb-f590-4930-9975-aa12dc267f2f': {'small': [],
      'medium': [],
      'large': [['https://www.pablo-ruiz-picasso.net/images/works/3936.jpg', 1]]},......}
```

This is what I'm trying to do using dict comprehension but it fails because the temporary list is over ridden due to for loop:

```
dct = {k:[x for x in vv] for k,v in ranked_imgs.items() for vk,vv in v.items()}
```

or something like this maybe :

```
dct = {k:sum(vv,[]) for k,v in ranked_imgs.items() for vk,vv in v.items()}
```

This is what the code will look like with comprehension:

```
# ranked_imgs_={}

# for k,v in ranked_imgs.items():
#     lst = []
#     for vk,vv in v.items():
#         for url in vv:
#             lst.append(url)
#     ranked_imgs_[k] = lst
```

I'm curious to know if there is a pythonic way to do this using dict comprehension!

Comment: What do you mean _"the temporary list is over ridden"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chain.from_iterable` may be a little better than the answer of @blhsing, it iterates by concatenating `v.values()`:

```
from itertools import chain
result = {k: list(chain.from_iterable(v.values())) for k, v in ranked_imgs.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expected output is a dict of lists, so you can use a list comprehension as the output value of a dict comprehension. Also note that you can iterate over `v.values()` instead of `v.items()` since you aren't using the keys (thanks to @MechanicPig for pointing it out):

```
dct = {k: [url for vv in v.values() for url in vv] for k, v in ranked_imgs.items()}
```

Comment: This is the same as the result of the questioner using the loop. I don't understand why someone voted against it?

Comment: In fact, `for vk, vv in v.items()` is unnecessary and can be written as `for vv in v.values()`